# NPM warning: 'unsupported engine'

Tags: node.js, npm, vite

I entered the command `npm install -D tailwind css postcss autoprefixer vite` in VS-Code.

My environment is:

- NPM version: `8.1.2`
- Node.js version: `16.13.1`

Which resulted in following warning:

```
npm WARN idealTree Removing dependencies.vite in favor of devDependencies.vite
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {    
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'amqplib@0.5.2',    
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <=9' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.1', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

My package.json is:

```json
{
  "name": "tailwind-css-part-7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "css": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwind": "^4.0.0",
    "vite": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "accepts": "^1.3.7",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "amqplib": "^0.5.2",
    "ansi-styles": "^3.2.1",
    "app-root-path": "^2.1.0",
    "array-flatten": "^1.1.1",
    "asn1": "^0.2.3",
    "async-limiter": "^1.0.1",
    "async-retry": "^1.2.3",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "basic-auth": "^2.0.1",
    "bitsyntax": "^0.0.4",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "browserslist": "^4.19.1",
    "buffer-equal-constant-time": "^1.0.1",
    "buffer-more-ints": "^0.0.2",
    "bytes": "^3.0.0",
    "call-bind": "^1.0.2",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001296",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "color-convert": "^1.9.3",
    "color-name": "^1.1.3",
    "commands-events": "^1.0.4",
    "comparejs": "^1.0.0",
    "compressible": "^2.0.18",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "content-disposition": "^0.5.2",
    "content-type": "^1.0.4",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "cookie-signature": "^1.0.6",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto2": "^2.0.0",
    "datasette": "^1.0.1",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "decode-uri-component": "^0.2.0",
    "define-properties": "^1.1.3",
    "depd": "^1.1.2",
    "destroy": "^1.0.4",
    "draht": "^1.0.1",
    "ecdsa-sig-formatter": "^1.0.11",
    "ee-first": "^1.1.1",
    "electron-to-chromium": "^1.4.35",
    "encodeurl": "^1.0.2",
    "es-abstract": "^1.19.1",
    "es-to-primitive": "^1.2.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.13.15",
    "esbuild-windows-64": "^0.13.15",
    "escalade": "^3.1.1",
    "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "etag": "^1.8.1",
    "eventemitter2": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
    "fast-json-stable-stringify": "^2.1.0",
    "finalhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "find-root": "^1.1.0",
    "flaschenpost": "^5.0.49",
    "formats": "^1.0.0",
    "forwarded": "^0.2.0",
    "fraction.js": "^4.1.2",
    "fresh": "^0.5.2",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
    "get-intrinsic": "^1.1.1",
    "get-own-enumerable-property-symbols": "^3.0.2",
    "get-symbol-description": "^1.0.0",
    "has": "^1.0.3",
    "has-bigints": "^1.0.1",
    "has-flag": "^3.0.0",
    "has-symbols": "^1.0.2",
    "has-tostringtag": "^1.0.0",
    "hase": "^2.0.0",
    "http-errors": "^1.6.3",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.23",
    "inherits": "^2.0.4",
    "internal-slot": "^1.0.3",
    "ipaddr.js": "^1.9.1",
    "is-bigint": "^1.0.4",
    "is-boolean-object": "^1.1.2",
    "is-callable": "^1.2.4",
    "is-core-module": "^2.8.0",
    "is-date-object": "^1.0.5",
    "is-negative-zero": "^2.0.2",
    "is-number-object": "^1.0.6",
    "is-obj": "^1.0.1",
    "is-regex": "^1.1.4",
    "is-regexp": "^1.0.0",
    "is-shared-array-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "is-string": "^1.0.7",
    "is-symbol": "^1.0.4",
    "is-weakref": "^1.0.2",
    "isarray": "^0.0.1",
    "json-lines": "^1.0.0",
    "json-schema-traverse": "^0.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "jwa": "^1.4.1",
    "jws": "^3.2.2",
    "limes": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lodash.includes": "^4.3.0",
    "lodash.isboolean": "^3.0.3",
    "lodash.isinteger": "^4.0.4",
    "lodash.isnumber": "^3.0.3",
    "lodash.isplainobject": "^4.0.6",
    "lodash.isstring": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.once": "^4.1.1",
    "lusca": "^1.6.1",
    "media-typer": "^0.3.0",
    "merge-descriptors": "^1.0.1",
    "methods": "^1.1.2",
    "mime": "^1.4.1",
    "mime-db": "^1.51.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.34",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "ms": "^2.0.0",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.30",
    "negotiator": "^0.6.2",
    "nocache": "^2.0.0",
    "node-releases": "^2.0.1",
    "node-rsa": "^0.4.2",
    "node-statsd": "^0.1.1",
    "normalize-range": "^0.1.2",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "object-inspect": "^1.12.0",
    "object-keys": "^1.1.1",
    "object.assign": "^4.1.2",
    "object.getownpropertydescriptors": "^2.1.3",
    "on-finished": "^2.3.0",
    "on-headers": "^1.0.2",
    "parseurl": "^1.3.3",
    "partof": "^1.0.0",
    "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
    "path-to-regexp": "^0.1.7",
    "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-value-parser": "^4.2.0",
    "processenv": "^1.1.0",
    "proxy-addr": "^2.0.7",
    "punycode": "^2.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.5.2",
    "range-parser": "^1.2.1",
    "raw-body": "^2.3.3",
    "readable-stream": "^1.1.14",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "resolve": "^1.21.0",
    "retry": "^0.12.0",
    "rollup": "^2.63.0",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.1.2",
    "safer-buffer": "^2.1.2",
    "semver": "^5.7.1",
    "send": "^0.16.2",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
    "setprototypeof": "^1.1.0",
    "sha-1": "^0.1.1",
    "side-channel": "^1.0.4",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1",
    "source-map-js": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
    "split2": "^3.0.0",
    "stack-trace": "^0.0.10",
    "statuses": "^1.4.0",
    "stethoskop": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "^0.10.31",
    "string.prototype.trimend": "^1.0.4",
    "string.prototype.trimstart": "^1.0.4",
    "stringify-object": "^3.3.0",
    "supports-color": "^5.5.0",
    "supports-preserve-symlinks-flag": "^1.0.0",
    "timer2": "^1.0.0",
    "tsscmp": "^1.0.6",
    "type-is": "^1.6.18",
    "unbox-primitive": "^1.0.1",
    "unpipe": "^1.0.0",
    "untildify": "^3.0.3",
    "uri-js": "^4.4.1",
    "util-deprecate": "^1.0.2",
    "util.promisify": "^1.0.0",
    "utils-merge": "^1.0.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "uuidv4": "^3.0.1",
    "varname": "^2.0.3",
    "vary": "^1.1.2",
    "which-boxed-primitive": "^1.0.2",
    "ws": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your `package.json` content here?

Comment: @RazLuvaton https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uLHLbJquCepDwXzlR1kGt0FFUjxx-wr5/view?usp=sharing this is link of my package .json

Comment: You can include the package json content in your question itself

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its not a breaking error, just means that some functionalities might not work as expected.
As this `npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <=9' }` line shows, the required node version for this package to work as intended is between 0.8 and 9 but you have node 16.

Comment: With this specific issue its because the OP installed the wrong tailwind package.

Answer (score 15):

It also happened to me while I was trying to install `tailwindcss` and I installed `tailwind` by mistake. Just uninstall it if that's also your case.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the problem I was having and I had no idea.

Answer (score 5):

You accidentally installed an old NPM library also called [Tailwind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind?activeTab=versions) which is not the one you are looking for. It has not been updated in 4 years and that's why its dependent on really old Node versions. Your looking for tailwindcss.
Steps to fix

1. npm uninstall tailwind,
2. npm install -D tailwindcss

Steps to confirm you have the wrong library installed

1. Check the pacakge.json file for tailwind in your list of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same warning when I was try to install `tailwind` in my project:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@eslint/eslintrc@1.3.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.16.1', npm: '8.2.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

So, I upgraded `node.js` version to `14.17.0`, and warning gone.
You can find release you need by this link -
https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: https://www.mend.io/free-developer-tools/blog/how-to-update-node-js-to-latest-version/?unapproved=6865&moderation-hash=7075e103381355e2b28c0e4999b00889#comment-6865

Answer (score 2):

You can delete your node_modules and remove the package-lock.json, then try to install again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I actually installed the "tailwind" npm package, not the "tailwindcss". I think removing "tailwind" and installing "tailwindcss" may work.

```
npm uninstall tailwind
```

then install tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

I use nvm and had node v20.11.0
Had this same error while installing tailwindcss in my react project. Instead of downgrading your node version, you can use the below lines:

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was having issues with a vite installation of dependent libraries but resolution was to update my version of @types/node and uninstalled tailwind (old / not updated) to tailwindcss.

npm install -d @types/node
npm uninstall tailwind
npm install -d tailwindcss

Answer (score -1):

Need to change the node version. you can use node version manager for that https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: I don't think downgrading from Node 16 to Node 9 is an acceptable solution.