# While laravel authentication package trying to install and run command npm install, it shows the warning

Tags: laravel, authentication, npm-install

```
PS F:\A. WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT\My Projects\SAIMUM\saimum> npm install
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'vite@3.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

added 66 packages, and audited 67 packages in 1m

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

what is the solution for it? can you tell me please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594844/npm-warning-unsupported-engine

Answer (score 0):

You are using node v15.8.0, but the message says it requires ^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0.

If it's your package.json with the engines field causing this issue, change it to say 16.0.0 or greater:

```
 "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
```